# Best C++ Library to Display an Image from a 2D Array

Tags: c++, image-processing, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D Array which contains an image I transferred from a binary file.  I would like to display this image and I was wondering what would be the best tool (C++ Library) to do this.

Simply, what C++ library can take a 2D array and display an image?

EDIT*
I think it would be best to be more specific.

I am trying to take a 2D array of 8-Bit Numeric values and index them into some sort of structure to display my image.

Matlab has a function to do this called imshow(X, Map) where Map is an n by 3 array of RGB values.  X is the 2D array.  Is there a similar function provided by a C++ library.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What format? ASCII art is an image too, you know...

Comment: Right now, all I know is that I have an array of unsigned 8 bit integers that is supposed to form a grayscale image.

Comment: If it helps in any way, I am converting code over from matlab to c++.  The image in matlab was displayed from a 2D array using imshow.

Comment: This is too broad. Are you using some framework already to display things on the screen? Then it most likely has something like `SetPixel`... Your image is just 256 shades of gray, you can use some simple API to display it.

Comment: how about SDL? it's more suited for many images though.

Comment: I would advertise Qt (see its QImage class). Oh, and there is also this nice plotting library called QWT that allows you visualising most scientific plots and so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a requirement to do all of it within C++, or is it OK to extend your toolchain? It sounds like you could combine C++ with e.g. [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) for this, with good results and little effort.

What you'd do in that case is to take your 2D array of numbers and print them (their string representation, not their bit representation) to `stdout`, one pixel row per line, with pixels separated by spaces (or tabs). Run program and redirect the output to a file:

```
$ ./yourprogram > img.dat
```

Then, create a gnuplot script that plots the image as you want. Gnuplot has [extensive documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html) that will help you get you started - if you download the pdf for the current version (4.6) and look under the heading "Image" (on page 53), that seems to do precisely what you want.

My main argument for this approach over e.g. OpenGL is that this is *really easy*. Writing to `stdout` is among the first things any C++ programmer learns, and gnuplot is designed to make plotting data easy. Admittedly, gnuplot does have a steep-ish learning curve, but not by far as steep as producing something of the same quality with OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `WinAPI`, you are free to paint into program window as you wish and it is the simplest way in my opinion. See [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/261009-bitmap-printing-tutorial-in-c-win32/) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1988/Guide-to-WIN32-Paint-for-beginners).

Otherwise I suggest you learn to use [OpenGL](https://www.google.cz/search?q=%20C%2b%2b%20start%20with%20opengl&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), which is I think considered to be mainstream today and has many more features, etc.

Comment: OpenGL is a 3D gfx library - a bit overkill for displaying a 2D image.